# Unparseable date

Tags: java, date

I have a string-date "31-Dec", and pattern "dd-MMM". And the next code

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
formatter.setTimeZone(timeZone);
formatter.parse(input);
```

generates exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "31-Dec"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)....
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You do not have a year in your date. What result do you expect exactly?

Comment: Locale.getDefault().toString() prints ru_RU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem could be that your `Locale` is not english. Try this:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
    System.out.println(formatter.parse("31-Dec"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This returns for me:

> Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 CET 1970

As you are missing a year in your date string, you see that it automatically inserts `1970` as year.

Comment: Yes, you was right. My problem is really in Locale. My default Locale is ru_RU.

Sorry for such stupid question.

Comment: Don't worry, that happens. It's actually a good thing, when problems turn out to be quite easily solvable. :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a simple example that works on my machine.  Give it a shot on yours, it may help you pinpoint the problem.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "31-Dec";
        String pattern = "dd-MMMM";

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        try {
            Date date = formatter.parse(data);
            System.out.println(date.getDate());
            System.out.println(date.getMonth());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think , Your input string (representing date ) is not in the format described in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this---

```
    String pattern = "dd-MMM";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
String input = "31-Dec";
try
{
    dateFormat.parse(input);
    Calendar cal = dateFormat.getCalendar();
    System.out.println("Day "+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    System.out.println("MONTH "+ cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

}catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```java
MonthDay
    .parse(
        "31-Dec" ,
        DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern ( "dd-MMM" )
            .withLocale ( Locale.US )
    )
```

## `MonthDay`

> string-date "31-Dec", and pattern "dd-MMM"

There's a class for that: [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html) in the *java.time* framework in Java 8+.

You were using the `Calendar` class, which represents a moment, a point on the timeline. But your input is not a moment, it is merely a month and day-of-month. So your input lacks the necessary information to make a `Calendar` instance. Furthermore, `Calendar` is a terribly flawed class that was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

To parse your input text as a `MonthDay` object, define a formatting pattern in a `DateTimeFormatter` object. Be sure to specify the `Locale` by which to understand the localized name of month.

```java
String input = "31-Dec";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd-MMM" ).withLocale ( Locale.US );
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse ( input , f );
```

### ISO 8601

Generate text representing that value in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The first hyphen in the result represents the omitted year.

> md.toString() = --12-31

The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```java
String standardText = md.toString ( );
MonthDay md2 = MonthDay.parse ( standardText );
```

I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about using only the standard ISO 8601 formats for exchanging date-time values as text.